# Problemas com rotas laravel 5.2 e servidor AWS EC2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.2

Estou com problemas ao subir meu projeto para hospedagem, quando acesso ao serviço via `localhost` tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém quando subo meu projeto para o servidor ele apresenta o erro:

[image: Imagem do erro]

Meu arquivo de rota routes.php esta assim:

```
<?php

Route::singularResourceParameters();

Route::auth();

/// METODOS DELETE

Route::post('/produtos/delete', [
    'uses' => 'ProdutoController@delete',
    'as' => 'produtos.delete'
]);

Route::post('/imagens/delete', [
    'uses' => 'ImagemController@delete',
    'as' => 'imagens.delete'
]);

Route::post('/categorias/delete', [
    'uses' => 'CategoriaController@delete',
    'as' => 'categorias.delete'
]);

Route::post('/subcategorias/delete', [
    'uses' => 'SubCategoriaController@delete',
    'as' => 'subcategorias.delete'
]);

Route::post('/embalagens/delete', [
    'uses' => 'EmbalagemController@delete',
    'as' => 'embalagens.delete'
]);

Route::post('/tipo_produtos/delete', [
    'uses' => 'TipoProdutoController@delete',
    'as' => 'tipo_produtos.delete'
]);


///

Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function (){
    Route::resource('clientes', 'ClienteController');
    Route::resource('categorias', 'CategoriaController');
    Route::resource('embalagens', 'EmbalagemController');
    Route::resource('tipo_produtos', 'TipoProdutoController');
    Route::resource('subcategorias', 'SubCategoriaController');
    Route::resource('produtos', 'ProdutoController');
    Route::resource('loteproduto', 'LoteProdutoController');
});

Route::get('/clientes/encomenda/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ClienteController@encomenda',
    'as' => 'dashboard.index'
]);

///ROTA DASHBOARD

Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@index',
    'as' => 'dashboard.index'
]);

Route::get('/produzir', [
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@produzir',
    'as' => 'dashboard.produzir'
]);

Route::get('/entregar', [
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@entregar',
    'as' => 'dashboard.entregar'
]);
///FIM ROTA DASHBOARD

///ROTA PEDIDOS

Route::get('/pedidos/pendentes', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@pendentes',
    'as' => 'pedidos.pendentes'
]);

Route::get('/pedidos/entrega', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@entrega',
    'as' => 'pedidos.entrega'
]);

Route::get('/pedidos/todos', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@todos',
    'as' => 'pedidos.todos'
]);

Route::get('/pedidos/cancelados', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@cancelados',
    'as' => 'pedidos.cancelados'
]);

Route::get('/pedidos/concluidos', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@concluidos',
    'as' => 'pedidos.concluidos'
]);

Route::get('/pedidos/produzindo', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@produzindo',
    'as' => 'pedidos.produzindo'
]);

Route::get('/pedidos/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@show',
    'as' => 'pedidos.show'
]);

Route::post('/pedidos', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@mudarStatus',
    'as' => 'pedidos.mudar'
]);

Route::get('/pedidos/efetivar/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'PedidoController@efetivar',
    'as' => 'pedidos.efetivar'
]);
///FIM ROTA PEDIDOS


Route::get('/parametros', [
    'uses' => 'ParametrosController@index',
    'as' => 'parametros.efetivar'
]);

Route::PATCH('/parametros', [
    'uses' => 'ParametrosController@editar',
    'as' => 'parametros.editar'
]);

Route::get('/login', function (){
    return view('auth.login');
});

///ROTA IMAGENS

Route::get('/imagens/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ImagemController@mostrar',
    'as' => 'imagens.index'
]);


Route::get('/imagens/create/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ImagemController@create',
    'as' => 'imagens.create'
]);

Route::post('/imagens/store', [
    'uses' => 'ImagemController@store',
    'as' => 'imagens.store'
]);

Route::get('/imagens/mostrar/{id?}', [
    'uses' => 'ImagemController@show',
    'as' => 'imagens.show'
]);

///FIM ROTA IMAGENS

///ROTA LOTE
Route::get('/lotes/imprimir/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'LoteProdutoController@print',
    'as' => 'lotes.print'
]);

Route::get('/lotes/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'LoteProdutoController@mostrar',
    'as' => 'lotes.index'
]);

Route::get('/lotes/create/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'LoteProdutoController@create',
    'as' => 'lotes.create'
]);

Route::post('/lotes/store', [
    'uses' => 'LoteProdutoController@store',
    'as' => 'lotes.store'
]);

///FIM ROTA LOTE

///ROTA RELATORIO
Route::get('/relatorio/pedidos', [
    'uses' => 'RelatorioController@pedidos',
    'as' => 'relatorio.pedidos'
]);

Route::post('/relatorio/pedidos', [
    'uses' => 'RelatorioController@Postpedidos',
    'as' => 'relatorio.Postpedidos'
]);

Route::get('/relatorio/compras', [
    'uses' => 'RelatorioController@compras',
    'as' => 'relatorio.compras'
]);

Route::get('/relatorio/entregas', [
    'uses' => 'RelatorioController@entregas',
    'as' => 'relatorio.entregas'
]);

Route::get('/relatorio/clientes', [
    'uses' => 'RelatorioController@clientes',
    'as' => 'relatorio.clientes'
]);

Route::post('/relatorio/clientes', [
    'uses' => 'RelatorioController@Postclientes',
    'as' => 'relatorio.Postclientes'
]);
///FIM ROTA RELATORIO
```

Certa vez vi uma questão que teria que mudar algo em minahs rotas pois o problema estava no group, porém não conseguir identifica aonde vi o erro. Na verdade nem bem sei se é isto mesmo.

> Em minha tentativa de solucionar o problema, como tenho controle total do servidor eu fiz as alterações fazendo com que meu documentRoot fosse direto para pasta public, isto não solucionou meu problema, continuou o mesmo.
>   Os comandos que utilizei são:
>
> > sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
> >     sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
> >     sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não é duplicata pois tentei solucionar daquela maneira e pesistiu o erro. Se você let minha pergunta todo vai ver que estou achando que é problemas nas rotas

Comment: Se acessar somente `http://localhost/` ele funciona? Note que a minha resposta explica **mais de uma** maneira de fazer e pela sua imagem você está usando `/plubic`

Comment: Não tem como acessar localhost, porque é um servidor dedicado da AWS(Amazon Web Service) mais preciso o EC2

Comment: Ok, mas de que maneira vc configurou o Laravel nele, foi pelo `DocumentRoot` e o `Directory` do Apache ou pelo .htaccess ou moveu o conteudo de public para raiz (aonde ficam os arquivos, como `/var/www`)?

Comment: Eu fiz as atualizações do documentRoot do Apache2, as outras não entendi muito bem como deveria faze3r

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51612/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-renan-rodrigues).

Comment: O padrão do Apache2, é a pasta /var/www/html/{Aqui vem meus arquivos inclusive a pasta public do laravel} a unica coisa que fiz foi alterar o caminho em vez da /var/www/html para /var/www/html/public, para ele ir direto para página, e funcionou, porém continuou com o mesmo erro de 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: Entra no chat para continuarmos por favor

Comment: @RenanRodrigues tem como configurar para a pasta `public`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Ja fiz isto, hoje esta configurado para ir direto para pasta public